# What date format is "ds1248083197360"?

Tags: date-format

As the question states, what date format is "ds1248083197360" ? Is this a standard date format or a custom one to an application?

**ds1248083197360** is **20/07/2009** (or in US format, **07/20/2009**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this might be miliseconds after 1.january year 1970 GMT 00:00. In this case, your example is 20.07.2009 10:46:37,360

Comment: I get "Mon Jul 20 2009 11:46:37 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)" from Epoch Converter, so that would make it 9:46 GMT (aka UTC) and not 10:46. Still the same date, though. :)

Answer (score 3):

It is probably the Unix time format, specified i milliseconds, meaning that it's the number of milliseconds since January 1st 1970. [Wikipedia's entry on Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

1248083197.360 is Monday the 20th of July 2009 09:46:37.360 GMT.